# Generalized electromagnetic angular momentum

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum

Linear momentum has a generalization when electromagnetic vector potential is present:

$$m {\bf v} + q \bf{A} $$

Likewise for energy we have

$$\frac{mv^2} {2} + q \phi $$

I wonder if there is an equivalent expression for a generalized angular momentum, but I haven't seen it anywhere. If one tries to build this from the linear momentum, it seems we reach something like:

$$I \omega + q \int \bf{r} \times\bf{A} dl $$

Does it look correct to you?

Comment: Can you explain your idea for the generalized angular momentum? As far as I know, the generalized angular momentum is just ${\vec q} \times \frac {\partial L} {\partial \dot{\vec q}}$, so in your case $\vec r \times (m \vec v + q \vec A) = \vec L + q \vec r \times \vec A$.

Comment: *Does it look correct to you?* It looks dimensionally *in*correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the generalized momentum for electromagnetism follows from the force law. Star with the force then collect the time derivatives on one side.

$\vec{F}=q\vec{E}+q\vec{v}\times \vec{B}=q(-\nabla V-\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t})+q\vec{v}\times (\nabla \times \vec{A})$

$\epsilon_{ijk}v_j(\epsilon_{kab}\frac{\partial A_b}{\partial a})$

$v_j(\delta_{ia}\delta_{bj}-\delta_{ib}\delta_{aj})\frac{\partial A_b}{\partial a}=v_j\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial i}-v_j\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial j}=\nabla(\vec{A}\cdot \vec{v})-(\vec{v}\cdot \nabla)\vec{A}$

$\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}=\vec{F}=-q\nabla V-q\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}+\nabla(q\vec{A}\cdot \vec{v})-(\vec{v}\cdot \nabla)(q\vec{A}) $

$\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{p}+q\vec{A})=-q\nabla V+\nabla(q\vec{A}\cdot v)-(\vec{v}\cdot \nabla)(q\vec{A})$

---

$\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times \vec{F}=q\vec{r}\times \vec{E}+q[\vec{r}\times(\vec{v}\times \vec{B})]=q\vec{r}\times \vec{E}+q[\vec{v}(\vec{r}\cdot \vec{B})-\vec{B}(\vec{r}\cdot \vec{v})]$

$\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}=\vec{\tau}=q\vec{r}\times (-\nabla V-\frac{d\vec{A}}{dt})+q\vec{v}[\vec{r}\cdot (\nabla \times \vec{A})]-q(\nabla \times \vec{A})(\vec{r}\cdot \vec{v})$

$\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{L}+\vec{r}\times q\vec{A})=-q\vec{r}\times\nabla V+q\vec{v}[\vec{r}\cdot (\nabla \times \vec{A})]-q(\vec{r}\cdot \vec{v})(\nabla \times \vec{A})$

So I think the generalized angular momentum is $\vec{L}+\vec{r}\times q\vec{A}$ as suggested by Tarik.